# React Native: Classes and Promises {Javascript}

Tags: javascript, oop, reactjs, react-native

I have few functions, i want to execute one after other. I'm not into OOP and this is gonna be my first. as i found on some articles, i should define a class with methods instead of functions. what is the best way to do that? should it look like this :

```js
export default class SomeClass extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  
  testFunc(){
    this.funcA = funcA();
    this.funcB = funcB();
  }
  
  funcA(){
    console.log('Hello from funcA');
  }
  
  funcB(){
    console.log('Hello from funcB');
  }
  
  componentWillMount(){
    testFunc
      .funcA()
      .then(funcB())
  }
}
```

I just need to execute funcB when funcA is finished executing. How can i achieve that?

Comment: There's nothing asynchronous in the example code shown in the question, so why would you use promises?

Comment: "*`this.funcA = funcA();`*" is wrong for sure, but I don't know what you actually wanted to do either

Comment: @Bergi , i'm not sure if i should i use promises or callbacks. i have few functions that i need to execute one after the other. currently my problem is functions in my app are running before the previous one finishes. how can i solve this? can you give an example?

Comment: You definitely should use promises over callbacks. Try to find some tutorials and learn about them. Then please ask a specific question about what you need.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi , i will do that.

Comment: @Bergi Why not generator in react?

Comment: @MyMasterPeice What do you mean? Generator functions?

Comment: @MyMasterPeice could you please tell more about that?

Comment: @Bergi Yes generator function from ES6 , which is basically cleaner way to write promises instead

Comment: @Ataomega Please just look over generator from ES6 features ->https://davidwalsh.name/es6-generators

Comment: @MyMasterPeice generator functions are not a replacement for promises. They supplement them, but are rather ugly. You should not use them anyway, ES8 async/await is here. In any case, you have to learn about plain promises at first.

Comment: @Bergi but most popular library in react like Saga does uses this generators !

Comment: @MyMasterPeice And it's outdated in a few months, yes. Generators were a popular hack until async/await was finished.

Comment: @Bergi i'm still searching for a await/async example in react-native , no success so far. i would really appreciate it if you could give a link or a simple example

Comment: @Ataomega https://blog.callstack.io/es8-and-beyond-d8e2c49e7ca#.sroe832uz ......http://stackabuse.com/node-js-async-await-in-es7/

Comment: @MyMasterPeice Thanks